# how can i show multiple indenepdent template in top level of telerik radgridview

Tags: winforms, templates, telerik, radgridview

```
 hello:
  i want add multiple template to radgridview and show templates in tabbed style ,
my templates is independent and no relation to each other, 
when i add templates to masterTemplate and set datasource of my templates,
datagrid is show empty grid and templates is not visible.
some tried code :  
Add Template Section:
```

```
                            GridViewTemplate gvt = new GridViewTemplate();
                        gvt.AllowDeleteRow = false;
                        gvt.AllowEditRow = false;
                        gvt.ShowTotals = true;
                        gvt.Caption = SubCaption[i];
                        radResult.MasterTemplate.Templates.Add(gvt);
                        radResult.Refresh();
```

Set Data Source Section that Indexnumber is template index:

```
            radResult.MasterTemplate.Templates[IndexNumber].DataSource = dtl;
            radResult.MasterTemplate.Templates[IndexNumber].Refresh();
            radResult.Refresh();
```

my desired View is :
[RadGridView target view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VDXx.jpg)

how must i do that?
thanks advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadGridView offers only one master level via the MasterGridViewTemplate. You can add as many child GridViewTemplates to the master level as you need. More information is available here: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/hierarchical-grid/hierarchy-of-one-to-many-relations

However, this requires a relation between the MasterTemplate and each of the child GridViewTemplates.

In order to achieve your design from the screenshot for a tabbed view in RadGridView on the parent level, I can suggest the following approaches:

1. Use a single RadGridView instance and set up a hierarchy with [load on demand](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/hierarchical-grid/load-on-demand-hierarchy). For this purpose, it would be necessary to add a dummy row for the master level and keep it expanded. The following code snippet shows how to achieve it:

   ```
        private void RadForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'nwindDataSet.Products' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.productsTableAdapter.Fill(this.nwindDataSet.Products);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'nwindDataSet.Orders' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.ordersTableAdapter.Fill(this.nwindDataSet.Orders);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'nwindDataSet.Categories' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.categoriesTableAdapter.Fill(this.nwindDataSet.Categories);

        this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add("MasterLevel");
        this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.AllowAddNewRow = false;
        this.radGridView1.ShowColumnHeaders = false;
        this.radGridView1.ShowGroupPanel = false;

        GridViewTemplate childTemplateCategories = new GridViewTemplate();
        childTemplateCategories.Caption = "Categories";
        foreach (DataColumn col in this.nwindDataSet.Categories.Columns)
        {
            childTemplateCategories.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
        }
        childTemplateCategories.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        this.radGridView1.Templates.Add(childTemplateCategories);
        childTemplateCategories.HierarchyDataProvider = new GridViewEventDataProvider(childTemplateCategories);

        GridViewTemplate childTemplateProducts = new GridViewTemplate();
        childTemplateProducts.Caption = "Products";
        foreach (DataColumn col in this.nwindDataSet.Products.Columns)
        {
            childTemplateProducts.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
        }
        childTemplateProducts.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        this.radGridView1.Templates.Add(childTemplateProducts);
        childTemplateProducts.HierarchyDataProvider = new GridViewEventDataProvider(childTemplateProducts);

        GridViewTemplate childTemplateOrders = new GridViewTemplate();
        childTemplateOrders.Caption = "Orders";
        foreach (DataColumn col in this.nwindDataSet.Orders.Columns)
        {
            childTemplateOrders.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
        }
        childTemplateOrders.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        this.radGridView1.Templates.Add(childTemplateOrders);
        childTemplateOrders.HierarchyDataProvider = new GridViewEventDataProvider(childTemplateOrders);

        this.radGridView1.RowSourceNeeded += new GridViewRowSourceNeededEventHandler(radGridView1_RowSourceNeeded);

        this.radGridView1.Rows.Add("Master");
        this.radGridView1.Rows[0].IsExpanded = true; 
    }

    private void radGridView1_RowSourceNeeded(object sender, GridViewRowSourceNeededEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Template.Caption == "Categories")
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in this.nwindDataSet.Categories.Rows)
            {
                GridViewRowInfo r = e.Template.Rows.NewRow();
                foreach (GridViewCellInfo cell in r.Cells)
                {
                    cell.Value = row[cell.ColumnInfo.Name];
                }
                e.SourceCollection.Add(r);
            }
        }
        else if (e.Template.Caption == "Products")
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in this.nwindDataSet.Products.Rows)
            {
                GridViewRowInfo r = e.Template.Rows.NewRow();
                foreach (GridViewCellInfo cell in r.Cells)
                {
                    cell.Value = row[cell.ColumnInfo.Name];
                }
                e.SourceCollection.Add(r);
            }
        }
        else if (e.Template.Caption == "Orders")
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in this.nwindDataSet.Orders.Rows)
            {
                GridViewRowInfo r = e.Template.Rows.NewRow();
                foreach (GridViewCellInfo cell in r.Cells)
                {
                    cell.Value = row[cell.ColumnInfo.Name];
                }
                e.SourceCollection.Add(r);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

[image]

2. Use a [RadDock](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/dock/overview) or a [RadPageView](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/pageview/overview) and add as many tabbed documents/pages as you need. Then, on each tab/page add a separate RadGridView control and populate it with the relevant data.

Feel free to use this approach which suits your requirements best.